# Get sum of rows of customers

Tags: mysql, sum

How can I get the sum of each customer's hours?
My data looks like this

```
  Customer  |   Hours
   C1       |    15
   C1       |    13
   C3       |    23
   C4       |    10
   C4       |    5
```

Customer and Hours are in a separate tables.
I did my query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.Customer
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.Customer is not null
ORDER BY t2.Customer ASC
```

And the result of this is

```
Customer
C1
C3
C4
```

I want to do next is to sum the hours of the customers so the output would look like this:

```
Customer   |    Hours
C1         |    28
C3         |    23
C4         |    15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `group by` statement, something like this:

```
SELECT t2.Customer, sum(t1.hours) as hours
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.Customer is not null
GROUP BY t2.Customer
ORDER BY t2.Customer ASC;
```

Comment: How come I got a syntax error when I added `WITH ROLLUP` at the bottom of the code? It says `...check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ROLLUP'`

Comment: `with rollup` has been supported by MySQL for many, many years.  The correct syntax in this query would be `group by t2.Customer with rollup`.